# else statement not working. how to close loop when nothing is entered?

Tags: python

else statement not working.  how to close loop when nothing is entered? suggestions on how to approach?

```
def main():
    print "~*~*~*~*~*~ Timbuktu Archery Contest ~*~*~*~*~*~"
    archerList = [] #list
    timeList = [] #list2
    name = raw_input ("Enter contestants first name: ")
    s = str(name)
    archerList.append(name)
    while name > 0:
        time = raw_input ("Enter time (in milliseconds) for %s: " % s)
        timeList.append(time)
        name = raw_input ("Enter contestants first name: ")
        s = str(name)
        archerList.append(name)
    else:
        name == ""
        print "Slowest archer was " , min(timeList)
        print "Fastest archer was " , max(timeList)
```

Comment: What do you mean by nothing is entered? And where?

Comment: `raw_input` takes the input as string, what do you get by doing `> 0` with it? If you want a number from the `raw_input`, better cast it to `int`...

Comment: And if you are reading a number, you should probably first change the variable name from `name` to something that really signifies holding a nnumeric vcalue.

Answer (score 2):

To loop until an empty name is given:

```
while name:
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
while len(name) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape from loop if nothing is entered by using this if-else construct

```
if (name==''):
    break
else:
    <job to be done>
```

Comment: In Python you can have `if...else`, `for...else`, `while...else`, `try...else`.

Answer (score 0):

this is more pythonic. DRY = Dont Repeat Yourself.

```
def main():
    print "~*~*~*~*~*~ Timbuktu Archery Contest ~*~*~*~*~*~"
    min = max = 0
    while True:
        name = raw_input ("Enter contestants first name: ")
        if not name:
            break
        start = raw_input ("Enter time (in milliseconds) for %s: " % name)
        min = start if start < min else min
        max = start if start > max else max
    print "Slowest archer was %i" % min
    print "Fastest archer was %i" % max
```

points to consider:

- I removed `archerList` as you don't get values from it in your code
- what happens if archers achieve the same time?
- the `"slowest archer was..."` actually tells us the slowest archer's time, not their name